# Keep objects in one objectArray which have an id value found in another objectArray

Tags: php, arrays, object, filtering, intersection

I'm trying to use `array_filter()` to filter an array of objects, they share a common value which is `warehouse_id`.

```
$warehouse_1 = new warehouse(1, 100, [1,2,3,4]);
$warehouse_2 = new warehouse(2, 1100, [1,2,3,4]);
$warehouse_3 = new warehouse(3, 12000, [1,2,3,4]);
$warehouse_4 = new warehouse(4, 130000, [1,2,3,4]);
$warehouse_5 = new warehouse(5, 1400000, [1,2,3,4]);

$inventory_feed_1 = new inventory_feed(12, 1, "2as21332kjd");
$inventory_feed_2 = new inventory_feed(10, 2, "2123asagfrtsdd");
$inventory_feed_3 = new inventory_feed(11, 3, "2as1231sds2d");
$inventory_feed_4 = new inventory_feed(13, 4, "2as1231sds2d");
$inventory_feed_5 = new inventory_feed(14, 5, "2as1231sds2d");

$ifeeds = ["a" => $inventory_feed_1, "b" => $inventory_feed_2, "c" => $inventory_feed_3];
$warehouses = [$warehouse_1, $warehouse_2, $warehouse_3, $warehouse_4, $warehouse_5];

$warehouses_filtered = array_filter(
  $warehouses,
  function ($warehouse) use ($ifeeds) {
    foreach($ifeeds as $ifeed_id => $ifeed) {
      return $ifeed->getWarehouseId() == $warehouse->getId();
  });

echo count($warehouses_filtered);
```

The desired output should be `[$warehouse_1, $warehouse_2, $warehouse_3]`
but it always returns me the original one (`5`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning on the first iteration of the `foreach` loop, so you're only testing whether the warehouse matches the first feed.

You should return true as soon as you find a match, but not return false until you get all the way through the loop without finding a match.

```
$warehouses_filtered = array_filter(
  $warehouses,
  function ($warehouse) use ($ifeeds) {
    foreach($ifeeds as $ifeed_id => $ifeed) {
      if ($ifeed->getWarehouseId() == $warehouse->getId()) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  });
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/z0feG8)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid excessive method calls inside of a nested structure, prepare for the filtration process by populating a lookup/map of warehouse ids from the feeds array.  The efficiency / time complexity will be good because only two linear loops will be executed.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/mi5em))

```
$feedMap = array_fill_keys(
    array_map(fn($obj) => $obj->getWarehouseId(), $ifeeds), // use ids as keys
    true // this could by any non-null value
);

$warehouses_filtered = array_filter(
    $warehouses,
    fn($warehouseObj) => isset($feedMap[$warehouse->getId()]) // keep if in the lookup
);

var_export($warehouses_filtered);
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to do it without any temporary maps and wish to use a native intersection function, then `array_uintersect()` is the best tool. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/83qWB))

```
var_export(
    array_uintersect(
        $warehouses,
        $ifeeds,
        fn($a, $b) => (method_exists($a, 'getId') ? $a->getId() : $a->getWarehouseId())
                      <=>
                      (method_exists($b, 'getId') ? $b->getId() : $b->getWarehouseId())
    )
);
```

Both snippets above will return the same result which is an array of warehouse objects containing ids found as warehouseIds in the `$ifeeds` objectArray.